# Unable to read an avi video with OpenCV 4.8

Tags: python, opencv, pytorch, computer-vision

I am facing a problem in open and reading an avi video of 1 minute with latest release of openCV. I installed it with PuTTY since I am actually working on a VM.
The same code works on Google Colab

```
        cap = cv2.VideoCapture(video_path)
        if not cap.isOpened():
            print(f"Error opening video file: {video_path}")
            return
```

while on VM I receive this error:

```
Unexpected list type. Expected: hdrl. Got: movi.
```

I used

```
(venv) ubuntu@bellizzi:~/data/ecg-fitness_raw-v1.0$ ffprobe /home/ubuntu/data/ecg-fitness_raw-v1.0/10/01/c920-1.avi  ffprobe version 3.4.11-0ubuntu0.1 Copyright (c) 2007-2022 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 7 (Ubuntu 7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version=0ubuntu0.1 --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --incdir=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu --enable-gpl --disable-stripping --enable-avresample --enable-avisynth --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libmysofa --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librubberband --enable-librsvg --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-omx --enable-openal --enable-opengl --enable-sdl2 --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libdrm --enable-libiec61883 --enable-chromaprint --enable-frei0r --enable-libopencv --enable-libx264 --enable-shared
  libavutil      55. 78.100 / 55. 78.100
  libavcodec     57.107.100 / 57.107.100
  libavformat    57. 83.100 / 57. 83.100
  libavdevice    57. 10.100 / 57. 10.100
  libavfilter     6.107.100 /  6.107.100
  libavresample   3.  7.  0 /  3.  7.  0
  libswscale      4.  8.100 /  4.  8.100
  libswresample   2.  9.100 /  2.  9.100
  libpostproc    54.  7.100 / 54.  7.100
Input #0, avi, from '/home/ubuntu/data/ecg-fitness_raw-v1.0/10/01/c920-1.avi':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf57.56.100
  Duration: 00:01:00.00, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 746501 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Video: rawvideo (I420 / 0x30323449), yuv420p, 1920x1080, 746910 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 30 tbn, 30 tbc
```

to see the codec and it is a readble format for openCV.
I checked if video were corrupted but they are not. Is it the AVI format or something else?

Thanks in advance for the help

I checked if video were corrupted but they are not. Is it the AVI format or something else?

I will share more code on the function

```
def process_video(video_path, video_csv_path, face_detector):
try:
    # Initialize video capture
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(video_path)
    print(video_path)
    if not cap.isOpened():
        print(f"Error opening video file: {video_path}")
        return

    rois_list = []
    resized_rois = []

    # Read the first frame
    ret, frame = cap.read()

    # List to save face regions frame by frame
    face_regions = []

    # Calculate the total number of frames in the video
    total_frames = int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT))
    frame_rate = cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS)

    # Limit the number of frames to analyze
    max_time_to_analyze_seconds = 15  # Adjust the desired time duration in seconds
    max_frames_to_analyze = int(max_time_to_analyze_seconds * frame_rate)
    df = pd.read_csv(video_csv_path)
    # Filtra il DataFrame per ottenere solo le righe entro i primi tot secondi
    df = df[df['milliseconds'] <= max_time_to_analyze_seconds * 1000]
    # Create a progress bar
    progress_bar = tqdm(total=min(total_frames, max_frames_to_analyze), position=0, leave=True,
                        desc=f'Processing Frames for {video_path}')

    frame_count = 0
```

Thanks in advance for the help

Comment: what is your video path? Show us the results of `print(video_path)`

Comment: I have a main directory with 16 subfolder. Each subfolder has 6 other subfolder. Every subfolder has a video so I have 96 videos in total

Comment: path /home/ubuntu/data/ecg-fitness_raw-v1.0/11/03/c920-1.avi (exmple of a path print)

Comment: did you try to copy the video in your working directory and just to try with `cap = cv2.VideoCapture("c920-1.avi")` ? FYI, there are no mention of incompatible .avi files with cv2

Comment: I tried but it is the same